# operation style: "rpc" not supported

Tags: java

I am a new bee to web services, I have developed a web service and published it on my local hosting to invoke the method inside a web service in separate maven project. I am using the below code to invoke the call:

```
String targetNamespace = "http://Webservice.Rahul.com/";
QName serviceName = new QName(targetNamespace,"CallWebserviceImplService");
//portName - Qualified name for the target service endpoint
QName portName = new QName(targetNamespace,"CallWebService");
//operationName - Qualified Name of the operation for which the Call object is to be       created.
QName operationName = new QName("add");
// Specify the location of the WSDL file
URL wsdlDocumentLocation = (on local host)
// Create an instance of service factory
ServiceFactory serviceFactory =  ServiceFactory.newInstance();
//Create a service object to act as a factory for proxies.
Service service =  serviceFactory.createService(wsdlDocumentLocation, serviceName);
Call call = (Call) service.createCall(portName);
call.setProperty("javax.xml.rpc.soap.operation.style","rpc");
String name=(String) call.invoke(operationName, null);
```

But this is giving me the following exception:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test set: com.xaptum.router.SendSmsTest
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 63.994 sec <<< FAILURE!
main(com.xaptum.router.SendSmsTest)  Time elapsed: 63.947 sec  <<< ERROR!
operation style: "rpc" not supported
at      com.sun.xml.rpc.client.dii.BasicCall.unsupportedOperationStyleException(BasicCall.java:583)
at com.sun.xml.rpc.client.dii.BasicCall.invoke(BasicCall.java:515)
at com.sun.xml.rpc.client.dii.BasicCall.invoke(BasicCall.java:541)
at com.xaptum.commandrouter.DMService.DMService.PushConnector(DMService.java:173)
at com.xaptum.commandrouter.DMService.DMService.callRouteHandler(DMService.java:73)
at com.xaptum.router.SendSmsTest.main(SendSmsTest.java:99)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    un.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:53)
    apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:123)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:104)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at eflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at en.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:164)
at ven.sur
```

Why am I getting this error? Any help is much appreciated.

The webservice code is as below:

```
@WebService(endpointInterface="com.Rahul.Webservice.CallWebService")
@SOAPBinding(style=Style.RPC)
public class CallWebserviceImpl implements CallWebService{
@Override
@WebMethod
public String add();
```

}

Comment: Maybe it is a "document" style web service instead?  Deadlines suck, don't they?

Comment: Hi, its not document style:here is the webservice implemetation code

Comment: Check your classpath. Does it have the **all** correct JARs? Double check it.

Comment: I have javax.xml.rpc-api-1.1.1.jar,jaxrpc-impl-1.1.3_01.jar,jaxrpc-api-1.1.jar in my maven dependencies

Comment: What are their `<scope>`s? `provided`? They should have the same version of the server you are deploying the service. And should have the `<scope>provided</scope>` to minimize risks of jars conflicts.